# Azure Function App > Application settings safe to store in NodeJS public repo?

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, environment-variables

In Azure Function App > Application settings if we save any secret env variables and refer to the variable in the NodeJS code using process.env.API_AI_ACCESS_TOKEN, is it safe?

Or iF anyone else accesses the public repo and runs the code will it access my Azure resources and cost me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is basically not safe to store the secrets directly in the application settings of an Azure Function App.
- Rather you can use Azure Key Vault, to store and retrieve secrets securely and reference those secrets in your code.
- This way your secrets will be encrypted and access to the secrets is controlled.

**Approach:**

Enable System Identity in your *Function App->Settings-> Identity*.

[image]

- Create secret in your keyvault and add keyvault access to your function app principal.
- Select any template from the dropdown and search for your function app select in the principal section.

[image]
[image]

Follow the same to add the user to provide keyvault access.
[image]

Go to *Secrets->create a secret* and store your secret value.
[image]
[image]

Select the secret you have created and note the Secret Identifier to add it as setting in function app.
[image]

Access your secret from keyvault in your functionapp by configuring secret identifier in *Configuration-> Add Application settings*.

`@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<your_secret_identifier_Uri**)`
[image]

Get your application settings with its value in your code using
`const secret=process.env.secret`.
[image]

**Result:**

[image]

You can also achieve this by using Azure Key Vault SDK.